# How can I take windows services list from multiple servers?

Tags: windows, service, server, servicecontroller

I have a three servers and I want windows servers list these servers. for one server I writing this code and I listing Windows server names and status. `ServiceController.GetServices();` How can I do with multiple servers?

Comment: Just call GetServices() separately for each server, then merge the arrays.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Firstly thank you your replay. But I don't know how can I do. How should I proceed ? Do I need write application for each server ? for exapmle; for three server, 3 sub application and one main application ?

Comment: You don't need multiple applications.  To list the services on a remote server, you can use the GetServices(String) variant, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s21fd6th(v=vs.110).aspx